# How to use ngx-translate in module components?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I working on ngx-translate. I bring that to work in app.component.html as almost tutorials describe. But how to do this in the components of my modules? Do I have all the steps for every module, or is there an easier way? If I bring all the steps from app.module.ts to my.module.ts I got an error message on running ng serve.

```
ERROR in src/app/landing-page/home/home.component.html:4:22 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'translate'.
```

This is my home.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private translateServeice: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

This is my landingpage.module.ts

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
    
    export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
      return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
    }
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        HomeComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild(
          {
            loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
              deps: [HttpClient]
            },
          }
        )
        
      ],
      exports: [
        HomeComponent
      ]
    })
    export class LandingPageModule { }
```

Do I miss any references in my module, or is the way I’m doing this wrong?

What is the usually way to use ngx-translate in module components?

**[EDIT]**

This is my demo project: https://github.com/Christoph1972/angular-i18n-demo

Please can some one show how to to run it?

Comment: Since you're not in the AppModule, you should try `forChild()` instead of `forRoot(...)` ? Did you try restarting `ng serve` ?

Comment: Where should I use for child, in app.module or in my module? In app.module it fires the same error message. Yes I restated ng serve.

Comment: `forRoot(...)` in appModule, and `forChild()` in child module

Comment: How are you adding `translate` pipe inside your template?

Comment: I use the pipe in this way: <h1>{{'home.title' | translate}}</h1> This way works in app.component.html

Comment: I added my demo project to the thread. Please can any one show how to run it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just add TranslateModule into imports of component module

or make **SharedTranslateModule** who *import* and *export* **TranslateModule** and **add in to app.module.ts to imports**

worked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxvhje)

Comment: I added the TranslateModule to my component imports array. I committed to my git repo. Please can you have a look inside? I’m turning in a circle for hours.  
https://github.com/Christoph1972/angular-i18n-demo

Comment: https://github.com/Christoph1972/angular-i18n-demo/blob/master/src/app/landing-page/landing-page.module.ts#L19 make just "TranslateModule" without ".forChild(...)"

Comment: I did it again. Error message:  No pipe found with name 'translate' I updated my repo.

Comment: @Christoph1972 working fork from u here https://github.com/launcelot66/angular-i18n-demo

Comment: Thanks for the fork!  <h1>{{'home.title' | translate}}</h1> translate is underlined, error message: No pipe found with name 'translate'
Does it work on your computer, did you test it?

Comment: After restarting VSC the underlining disappeared.  But the h1 in RouterOutlet is empty, no error message.

Comment: Your routing setup doesn't shows the RouterOutlet 
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) }
];
When I change it back, the usually error message occurs again. No pipe....

Comment: @-Никита Середа could you check your created fork? It's not working as I mentioned.

Comment: @Christoph1972 answer updated, look stackblitz example

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hard work! Your solution is so different to the documentation of ngx-translate. I think the documentation is not good, especially for angular beginners. I realized this project is not updated/maintained for a long time (https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1300). I’ll have a look to the native i18n version of Angular and Transloco. Many thanks for the nice support!

Comment: Its 6 hours that I?m trying to fix "No pipe found with name 'translate'" but no way...

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar issue, issue gets resolved by adding home module to app.module.ts.

If you dont have home module then add home component to the declarations of app module file.

[image]

[image]